# Unhandled System.NullReferenceException in Form.Dispose() WinForms .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I have a WinForms .NET app that crashed on a user's computer.  The Windows Error Report said it was a System.NullReferenceException.

After using the instructions on this page (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx) I was able to determine the problem to have occurred in Form.Dispose(boolean).

However, since the .Dispose() method is part of .NET and not something that I wrote, is there any way that I can prevent it from happening again?  I am currently not able to reproduce the problem because I don't know exactly what steps to take to reproduce it.

If anyone has any insight on how I might figure out more detail to this issue, I would appreciate it.

EDIT:
To be clear, I am not calling .Dispose directly but rather am just calling .Close() in my code.

Below is the Windows Error Report information, followed by the output of windbg that I obtained by following the instructions in the link posted above.

If I'm reading this correctly, the issue occurred in .Dispose(), but perhaps I've misread the output?

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: MyApp.exe
Problem Signature 02: 0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 52fd3d6b
Problem Signature 04: MyApp
Problem Signature 05: 0.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 52fd3d6b
Problem Signature 07: 35b
Problem Signature 08: b5
Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException


0:013> !token2ee MyApp 06000035
Module:      000007fe98762f98
Assembly:    MyApp.exe
Token:       0000000006000035
MethodDesc:  000007fe98a75220
Name:        MyApp.Form_ColumnEditing.Dispose(Boolean)
JITTED Code Address: 000007fe98a159e0

0:013> !dumpil 000007fe98a75220
ilAddr = 00000000012c3a70
IL_0000: nop 
IL_0001: ldarg.1 
IL_0002: brfalse.s IL_000f
IL_0004: ldarg.0 
IL_0005: ldfld MyApp.Form_ColumnEditing::components
IL_000a: ldnull 
IL_000b: ceq 
IL_000d: br.s IL_0010
IL_000f: ldc.i4.1 
IL_0010: stloc.0 
IL_0011: ldloc.0 
IL_0012: brtrue.s IL_0022
IL_0014: nop 
IL_0015: ldarg.0 
IL_0016: ldfld MyApp.Form_ColumnEditing::components
IL_001b: callvirt System.IDisposable::Dispose 
IL_0020: nop 
IL_0021: nop 
IL_0022: ldarg.0 
IL_0023: ldarg.1 
IL_0024: call System.Windows.Forms.Form::Dispose 
IL_0029: nop 
IL_002a: ret
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. And, FYI, a form may override `Dispose`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: If, like he said, he can't reproduce it, he won't be able to produce a stack trace or get this answered.

Comment: @Magus: how do you know that neither the error report, nor the technique he used, have captured a full stack trace?

Comment: Form.Dispose() automatically disposes all of the child controls on the form.  Whose Dispose() method certainly don't have to be .NET framework code.  You cannot diagnose this without the exception's stack trace, you'll have to improve your error handling.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added more detail above, including the Problem Signature information.  Any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: So, you have the crash dump? What is the output of `!pe` command in Windbg?

Comment: @YK1 I do *not* have the crash dump.  As stated above, I used just the Windows Error Report information to produce the output shown.

Comment: I see, what is output of `!token2ee MyApp 0600035b`

Comment: @YK1 Thank you for the feedback!  I get completely different output using !token2ee MyApp 0600035b which I now realize is the CORRECT output, which means that .Dipose() is not where the problem is after all!